# Closure behaving unexpectedly

Tags: php, function, closures

I have a closure inside a function but when it is called the return value is not where i expected it to be.

```
public function test($name, $content)
{
     $test = "\t<div id=\"{$name}\">{$content()}</div>\n";
     return $test;
}
```

Instead of returning this...

```
<div id="name">content</div>
```

It instead returns...

```
content
<div id="name"></div>
```

If you have any idea how to fix this to display properly then i would be a very happy man, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't showed the `$content()` function, but from the symptoms I assume it *prints* the content instead of returning it. What happens is that the `test()` function calls the `$content()` function which displays the content and returns nothing, then `test()` returns and something else prints the return value.

To fix it simply have `$content()` return the content instead of printing it.

Answer (score -1):

Let the closure execute and catch what's returned.  Then insert the result:

```
public function test($name, $content)
{
     $insert = $content();
     $test = "\t<div id=\"{$name}\">{$insert}</div>\n";
     return $test;
}
```

Comment: If `$content()` would return the content to be printed, the original code would work just as well.

Comment: The problem was that i was echoing out the return instead of returning it to the function which caused the unexpected result, thanks for all your help!

Comment: The only possible issue left is the function you're passing as $content is echoing instead of returning values.